# Rankin-Selberg Convolution of newforms with different levels

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

Let $f \in \mathscr{S}_{k}(N,\chi)$ and $g \in \mathscr{S}_{k}(M,\psi)$ be newforms with $(N,M) = 1$. For $\Re(s) > 1$, I was able to derive an integral representation for the Rankin-Selberg convolution:
$$L(s,f \otimes g) = \frac{(4\pi)^{s+k-1}\pi^{s}}{\Gamma(s+k-1)\Gamma(s)}\int_{\mathscr{F}}f(z)\overline{g(z)}\Im(z)^{k}\frac{L(2s,\chi\psi)}{\zeta(2s)}E^{\ast}(z,s)\,d\mu.$$
where $E^{\ast}(z,s)$ is the completed real-analytic Eisenstein series. I'm trying to use this expression to derive a functional equation for $L(s,f \otimes g)$ but substiuting in the functional equations for the Dirichlet L-series, zeta function, and real-analytic Eisenstein series doesn't seem to give me what I want. The gamma factors don't symmetrize nicely as $s \to 1-s$ and I dont get the Fricke involutions of $f$ and $g$ to appear (I think they should appear because they give the dual $L$-functions for $L(s,f)$ and $L(s,g)$). Can anyone tell me what the functional equation should be and if I've made an error with this integral representation?

I was able to have sucess when I did all this on level $1$ ($N = M = 1$), since the Dirichlet $L$-series and zeta functions don't appear and thus the integrand is invariant as $s \to 1-s$ but I'm having trouble extending to the case with fixed weight but different levels.

Comment: You need your Eisenstein series to be for $\Gamma_0(MN)$ and you need to integrate over $\Gamma_0(MN) \backslash \mathbb{H}$. The functional equation for this Eisenstein series is a little complicated since it involves the corresponding Eisenstein series associated to the cusp at $0$ instead of the cusp at $\infty$. That should naturally introduce the Fricke involutions of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a reference where I can find a proof of the functional equation for the Eisnestein series? Or just a statement of the result? I've done it in the case when its just the standard real-analytic Eisenstein series but not for this modified version on a different congruence subgroup. Also, is this Rankin-Selberg convolution still a Selberg class $L$-function or is the functional equation somewhat more complicated because the different Eisenstein series on $\Gamma_{0}(NM)$ get invovled?

Comment: I think the functional equation for these Eisenstein series is in Iwaniec's book on spectral methods for automorphic forms. See also Matt Young's paper on Eisenstein newforms. Yes, the Rankin-Selberg convolution is always a Selberg class $L$-function.